# How to return multiple select queries from PostgreSQL's functions like we do in MS SQL Procedures

Tags: postgresql

I am currently working on PostgreSQL's functions. Like we return multiple result set in MS SQL procedures by writing multiple select queries, same thing I need to integrate in postgreSQL. I did study and came through following solution :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.summary_test( IN shoppedfromdate date, IN shoppedtodate date, IN enrollmentfromdate date, IN enrollmenttodate date )

RETURNS 

SETOF refcursor 
AS   
$my_body$

DECLARE Q1 refcursor;
DECLARE Q2 refcursor;

BEGIN
    OPEN Q1 for 
        Select  t_cs_dummy.text_data,t_cs_dummy.bigint_data from public.t_cs_dummy ;
    RETURN NEXT Q1;

    OPEN Q2 FOR 
        Select  date_data,datetime_data from public.t_cs_dummy ;
    RETURN NEXT Q2;



END;
$my_body$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 10;
```

Please let me know, Is this is proper way ? if 'No' then is there any alternative way to do so??

Comment: To my knowledge, `RETURNS SETOF refcursor` is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multiple_recordsets () RETURNS TABLE (id bigint)
AS $$
BEGIN 

    RETURN QUERY SELECT generate_series(1,10)::bigint v;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT generate_series(20,30)::bigint v;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT generate_series(100,110)::bigint v;
END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then call it with:

```
SELECT * FROM multiple_recordsets();
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It clearly works, and is still current in PG13, 5 years later.

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation of how it functions, with links to the official documentation.